# Удалить часть текста при помощи регулярных выражений

Tags: php

Нужно удалить из текста:

```
a:3:{s:4:"TEXT";s:45:"Текст";s:4:"TYPE";s:4:"HTML";}
```

Все кроме слова `Текст`, числа могут быть любыми. Делаю так:

```
$value = preg_replace("[a:[0-9]*:{s:[0-9]*:\"TEXT\";s:[0-9]*:\"]", '', $value);
$value = preg_replace("[\";s:[0-9]*:\"TYPE\";s:[0-9]*:\"HTML\";}]", '', $value);
```

Ничего не удаляется. Что делаю не так?

Comment: что на выходе хотите получить? что то не понятно...

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, на выходе должно остаться только слово `Текст`, все остальное надо удалить. Это слово - для примера, там на деле произвольный текст.

Comment: произвольный текст будет в переменной?

Comment: А зачем удалять? Во-первых это сериализованные данные, и судя по `s:45` сериализованные неправильно (если вы конечно не заменили весь текст на слово "текст" просто для примера). Во-вторых - если вы просто удалите какую-то часть текста, то даже правильно сериализованные данные станут __неправильными__ так как длина будет неверной. Поэтому не изобретайте велосипед. Десериализуйте данные, удалите из полученного массива то что надо, и сериализуйте обратно.

Answer (score 4):

не занимайтесь ерундой. перед вами массив строк сериализованный с помощью функции `serialize()`. Если из этого массива вам требуется удалить слово, то десериализуйте данные, удалите это вхождение, и упакуйте обратно.

```
$txt = "....";
$data = unserialize($txt);
```

если вы знаете, с какой позиции слово надо удалить, то

```
unset($data[1]);
```

Или использовать функции расхождения массиввов

```
$data = array_diff($data, ['Текст']);
```

Или использовать функции фильтрации (что кажется более правильным)

```
$data = array_filter($data, function($v){ return $v != 'Текст';});
```

и сериализовать обратно

```
$txt = serialize($data);
```

*зы: как уже замечено в комментариях, представленный формат некорректен `a:3` в начале обозначает, что это массив из трех элементов, у вас же их 4. А далее `s:45:` обозначает строку длиной 45, хотя у вас длина 4*

Использовать для данной задачи регулярные выражения - не корректно. Если данные и были правильными,то они станут неправильными, хотя бы из-за изменения длины массива после удаления слова